# get multiple file input in form submit with no selector but 'this' keyword or other way around

Tags: javascript, jquery

in single file upload, it can get file input by `this.image`

```
<form id="form">
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var inputfile = this.image; // -> that's ok
});
```

but if you have to deal with multiple file input `this` keyword does not work!

```
<form id="form">
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var inputfile = this.images; // -> that's not work!
});
```

**how can get multiple file input DOM for manipulation without selectors?**

Comment: `this.images; // -> that's not work!` – well, that‘s _not_ the name of your form field … Try `this['images[]']`

Comment: @CBroe how can I improve it?

Comment: @CBroe do you know a good reference for this kind of details and weird stuff

Comment: If anybody know good reference about this kind of detailed stuff just tell please?!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements explains why access via `this` works here to begin with. And the bracket notation used to access the property with a name containing “special characters”, is explained here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var inputfile = this['images[]'];`

thanks to @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

The input element has a [files attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files) but it is read only. The alternative is to create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object and add the files and send the formdata using AJAX.

When the form is submitted I listen for the submit event and stop the default behavior (posting the form). I create two new files (here SVGs). I get a **copy** of the formdata in the form and append the two new files to the formdata. After that I use AJAX for posting the new formdata object to the server.

The console.log will display the stuff that is in the formdata object.

```js
document.forms.pickfile.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let svg01 = ['<?xml version="1.0"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200"><rect fill="blue" width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0"/></svg>'];
  let file01 = new File(svg01, 'example01.svg', {type: 'image/svg'});
  
  let svg02 = ['<?xml version="1.0"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200"><rect fill="blue" width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0"/></svg>'];
  let file02 = new File(svg02, 'example02.svg', {type: 'image/svg'});

  let formData = new FormData(e.target);
  formData.append('images[]', file01, 'example01.svg');
  formData.append('images[]', file02, 'example02.svg');
  
  console.log([...formData.entries()]);

  fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
});
```

```html
<form name="pickfile">
  <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple />
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```